# Starting a DLL as a exe

Tags: c++, windows, dll, exe

Is it possible to load a native (C++) DLL as an executable?
preferablly straight from the memory without creating EXE on the hard-drive or something similar?

Comment: Why would you want to do this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm writing a debugger in C++ which can debug only it own kind. x64 can debug only x64 and x86 - only x86. Instead of providing 2 seperate exe's, one for each platfrom, I was thinking of checking which version is needed for the debuggee and then "create" its handling exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `rundll32.exe`. But you'd better know exactly what you're doing. I'm not sure, honestly.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft provides [`Rundll32.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) which can be used to execute DLL functions that have been explicitly coded to support this usage.

Answer (score 3):

What, specifically, would this mean? For example, what entry point would it use in the DLL?

The only way this would actually work would be if the DLL was specifically written to allow it. And if that were the case, then it's not exactly clear why you would not just create an executable file instead of a DLL in the first place.

Case in point is the RunDLL32.exe stub. It's designed to execute a function from a DLL [with a specific signature](http://support.microsoft.com/support/kb/articles/q164/7/87.asp) as the entry point. If the DLL wasn't specifically designed to comply with this signature, then [things don't go well](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx). If you *need* functionality like this, you might want to consider matching the function signature required by RunDLL32.exe and using it to "execute" your DLL.

Comment: I'm writing this DLL, so it will be written to allow it. I need to handle both x64 and x86 platforms but I don't want to provide 2 versions (what I'm doing - explained in the comment to my question) :)

Comment: @Idov: The standard pattern is to provide 2 versions. If it's a debugger, it's written for developers. I think they can manage to understand the difference between the x86 and x64 platforms, and successfully juggle two different executables. You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LoadLibrary` WinAPI call to load a DLL.